# Fubini's Theorem and General Minowski Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality

Suppose that $f$ is a positive function and $1\leq p<\infty$. Consider $$A=\int (\int f(x,y)^p\ dx)^{1/p}dy,\ B=(\int (\int f(x,y)\ dy)^p dx)^{1/p}.$$ Suppose all quantities are integrable and finite. Prove that $A \geq B$.

I think I'm supposed to use Fubini's Theorem alongside with the Minowski inequality, but I'm not sure how to apply it in the right way. How do I prove this?

Comment: This is called Minkowski's inequality for integrals. You can find a proof in Wikipedia.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4292693/why-do-we-need-fubinis-theorem-in-this-proof-of-minkowskis-inequality-for-inte?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

$$B=\sup_{g\ge 0\|g\|_q=1} \int g(x)\int f(x,y)dydx=\int\left(\int g(x)f(x,y)dx\right)dy\le \int \|f(\cdot, y)\|_pdy$$